# Convert Angular 8 application to static using Angular Universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have recently purchased a theme built using **Angular 8.1.2** from Themeforest.
My **client wants a fully static (HTML + vanilla JS)** version of this theme, to use in a fully server side rendered application.

Themeforest only had React and Angular versions, so I tried to use Angular Universal to convert my Angular 8 theme to a static site.

My full package.json is at https://pastebin.com/ga20p1CV
I am sharing the relevant part of package.json in the below

```
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run myapp:server:production --bundleDependencies all",
"build:prerender": "npm --max_old_space_size=8096 run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm --max_old_space_size=8096 run compile:server && npm run generate:prerender",
"build:ssr": "npm --max_old_space_size=8096 run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm --max_old_space_size=8096 run compile:server",
"compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
"generate:prerender": "cd dist && node prerender",
"serve:prerender": "cd dist/browser && http-server",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server"
```

**SSR is working using Universal**, and I can run the generated site in dist folder from Node server.

However, the HTML rendered by the Node server is still full of Angular directives. It is no different than the output rendered by ng build command.

[image]

I downloaded the HTML rendered by the Node server and ran it as a static web app. **If I change anything inside of**

```
<app> .... </app>
```

**it shows for a split second and then immediately is replaced** by the original content. That is, Angular is still rendering content on client side.

### Is there any way to stop the client side rendering of the DOM inside the 'app' tag?

Answer (score 0):

You'll always have angular components markup in your generated html.

Angular universal performs server side rendering of the requested page and sends that page's html to the client. Once the browser has finished rendering this page, the "normal" client-side angular app takes over for navigation and rendering.

Comment: The problem is that, anything I write inside of <app> tag is replaced in client side. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: How/when do you write inside the app tag?